# What is the best way to detect and recognize traffic signs in a picture?

Tags: deep-learning, object-recognition, object-detection

I'm working on a project for my college to recognize traffic signs in pictures. I searched a lot but can't find the best method to do it.

Can someone recommend me a paper, article, or even GitHub link that describes the best way to achieve this? It will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is helpful:
[Recognising Traffic Signs With 98% Accuracy Using Deep Learning, by Eddie Forson](https://towardsdatascience.com/recognizing-traffic-signs-with-over-98-accuracy-using-deep-learning-86737aedc2ab).

Greetings
Mario

Answer (score 1):

Here are some articles, the first three include code:

- [Deep Learning for Traffic Signs Recognition, by Moataz Elmasry, April 2, 2018](https://becominghuman.ai/deep-learning-for-traffic-signs-recognition-aead0ea7273)
- [Traffic Sign Classification with Keras and Deep Learning, by Adrian Rosebrock, November 4, 2019](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/11/04/traffic-sign-classification-with-keras-and-deep-learning/)
- [Traffic Sign Detection using Convolutional Neural Network, by Sanket Doshi, September 1, 2019](https://towardsdatascience.com/traffic-sign-detection-using-convolutional-neural-network-660fb32fe90e)
- [AI to manage road infrastructure via Google Street View, June 19, 2019](https://www.rmit.edu.au/news/all-news/2019/jun/street-view-signs)